# Razor .NET Default Layout string format the link

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, email, razor, string-formatting

I am trying to format the string from given ViewBag and it works just fine

```
<td align="left" width="60%"><img src="@String.Format("{0}/{1}/img/logo.png", 
ViewBag.PictureCDNName, ViewBag.DefaultTheme)" alt="@ViewBag.DefaultTheme"/></td>
```

when I am trying to use Model to get the variables i need it crushes

```
<td align="left" width="60%"><img src="@String.Format("{0}/{1}/img/logo.png", 
Model.PictureCDNName, Model.DefaultTheme)" alt="@Model.DefaultTheme"/></td>
```

is there a way to do this in the layout or am I doing it wrong?
the template is for email so it is pain for me.

```
@RenderBody()
```

is used to call the body of for layout and it contains `@model`

Comment: can you provide 1-the HTML output 2-the model definition at the top of your View.

Comment: `<img src="http://vms/Content/themes/DefaultTheme/img/logo.png" alt="DefaultTheme">` it is the output using `ViewBag`  
model is dynamic.
At the top of View there is none it renders in controller where I `return ViewBag("Render", model);`

Comment: you need to declare your model at the top of your view like `@model MyNamespace.Models.MyModel`. by that Razor engine will recognize your `Model`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your model at the top of your view like

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.MyModel
```

And in your controller

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();

    // other needed operations

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: If it is `layout` for `body` then `body` will have access to the `model`?

Comment: thing about the resulting HTML as a string sent to the client. it's just run by razor engine and output string is added to the HTML result. it can be an attribute value, a text somewhere or even javascript code.

Comment: in this case it means i can use model in view if i pass it at the top as it fits `@model MyModel...`

Comment: i don't understand you completely, but it should. please try it and let me know.

Comment: The thing is the model is dynamic and it is not given like that
the Model is created in method as
`var model = new {
 DefaultTheme = "DefaultTheme"
}`
and in the `@RenderBody()` it is found and it reads and everything is excelent but not in the layout

Comment: the problem here is that i don't understand why `model` is found in the body but not in the layout

Comment: maybe your outer layout has another model and that model is tried to be rendered, thus failed.

Comment: The structure of this email is to have 1 layout with different messages in it if I ask layout to grab some value from Model it does not see it if I ask Body to grab something it takes what it can

Answer (score 0):

```
  @section ImageRender
{
<td align="left" width="60%"><img src="@String.Format("{0}/{1}/img/logo.png", 
Model.PictureCDNName, Model.DefaultTheme)" alt="@Model.DefaultTheme"/></td>
}
```

This did the trick and now when i call the layout to display 
`@RenderSectioni("ImageRender",false)` it works - false is in case the link breaks so the link does not break the whole page
thank you, You helped me